# AngularJS returning undefined on first ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im a building a system that fetches new events based on the date sent to the API using AngularJS. I am currently still in in the learning stages of AngularJS so Im wondering is there something Im missing.

My problem is , even though the data loads correctly on the page load, when I click the button the first time I am getting `undefined` for `$scope.newEvents` even though it is successfully getting the data from the API (I can see in the console).

I was attempting to build a JSFiddle but I was having trouble getting the whole thing to work on it.

here is the html output...

The output...

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy:'-event_date' ">
        <span >{{event.event_date}},{{event.event_name}}, {{event.event_venue}}, {{event.event_description}} </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The get request in my js...

```
var eventApp = angular.module('eventApp', ['ngRoute']);


eventApp.factory("services", ['$http', function($http) {

    var apiBase = 'http://example.net/angular-api/'

    var service = {};

    service.getEvents = function(latest_date){
        return $http.get(apiBase + 'events?latest_date=' + latest_date);
    }

    return service;   
}]);
```

When the page loads its working fine, it makes a successful request and updates `$scope.events` ...

```
var date = new Date();

$scope.todays_date = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
    ('00' + (date.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' + 
    ('00' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + 
    ('00' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + 
    ('00' + date.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

$scope.events = [{}];

services.getEvents($scope.todays_date).then(function(data){
    $scope.events = data.data;

});
```

But when click the button that loads the `ng-click` function I am getting undefined for my data. I initially figured there was something wrong with the date format, but the fact that it is successfully getting the data is what is confusing me. The problems start at `then` below...

```
        $scope.addFiveNew = function (new_or_old) {

        if (new_or_old == 'new') {

            $scope.latest_date = $scope.getNewestDate();


            services.getEvents($scope.latest_date).then(function(data){
                $scope.newEvents = data.data;
            });

            console.log($scope.newEvents);

            // update the list (this is currently failing on first click)
            angular.forEach($scope.newEvents,function(item) {
                $scope.events.push(item);
            });


        }
```

this function in the controller creates the date to send...

```
$scope.getNewestDate = function() {
        var sortedArray = $filter('orderBy')($scope.events, 'event_date');
        var NewestDate = sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1].event_date;
        return NewestDate;
    };
```

Here is an example of some data...

```
{
 "event_id":"1",
 "event_name":"Event 1",
 "event_date":"2014-09-26 00:00:00",
 "event_venue":"Limerick",
 "event_description":"stuff"
}
```

Comment: Put the `forEach` inside the callback (after `$scope.newEvents = data.data;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the getEvents call on your service is returning a promise.  Calling .then on a promise will call the passed function asynchronously.  So, your $scope.newEvents = data.data; will get called after the rest of the statements in that block.  I think you can change your .then statement to  the following and it should work:

```
$scope.addFiveNew = function (new_or_old) {

    if (new_or_old == 'new') {

        $scope.latest_date = $scope.getNewestDate();

        services.getEvents($scope.latest_date).then(function(data){
            $scope.newEvents = data.data;
            console.log($scope.newEvents);
            // update the list (this is currently failing on first click)
            angular.forEach($scope.newEvents,function(item) {
                $scope.events.push(item);
            });
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The bit inside the `then` is asynchronous, so the rest of your code can run without the scope being updated by the return of your service method, right?

```
services.getEvents($scope.latest_date)
.then(function(data){            //whenever the service returns
  $scope.newEvents = data.data;  //update the scope

  console.log($scope.newEvents); //log the results

  // update the list
  angular.forEach($scope.newEvents,function(item) {
     $scope.events.push(item);
  });
});
```